# MySQL LIKE query not working

Tags: php, mysql

I m using some advanced mysql query for search some data from the database. But when I added LIKE `WHERE developer LIKE %Lanterra%` to the query, it will not work.

working query.

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM condo HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 2500",
    mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
    mysql_real_escape_string($center_lng),
    mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
    mysql_real_escape_string($radius));
```

When I added LIKE function.(not working)

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM condo WHERE developer LIKE %Lanterra% HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 2500",
    mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
    mysql_real_escape_string($center_lng),
    mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
    mysql_real_escape_string($radius));
```

Comment: Include single quote between `%Lanterra%`

Comment: Already try.
WHERE developer LIKE '%Lanterra%'

Comment: Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo).

Comment: Ok... can you see any kind of error reported from PHP or MySQL?

Comment: It would appear that no error checking is implemented.

Comment: there are no error reported from mysql or php.

Comment: @dumidu. If not working, then there is an error PHP or MySQL should report. Please, include this line at the top of your php file `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);`. Also, you can check your `php_error_log` and `mysql_error.log.

Comment: @bcesars yes. you are correct. There is an error.

Warning: sprintf(): Too few arguments in C:\wamp\www\gmap\test.php on line 29

Comment: I think the error occurs because of sprintf.

Comment: I think these two were the errors you were facing it. =)

Comment: How can I fix this ?

Comment: @dumidu why u use printf function in sql query? and assign to $query?

Comment: hmmm... Its because sprintf is recognizing `%Lanterra%` with `%` that can be declared and pass this value as placeholder. Try to escape then with this: `\%Lanterra\%`

Comment: Try to escape. but it also not working.

Comment: Did you include single quotes? I'll encourage you to check `mysql_error.log` as well.

Comment: There are no error in mysql_error.log. I try these too. WHERE developer LIKE '\%Lanterra\%'

Comment: Really the error is % mark. Because when I removed % mark it shows no errors. How to escape that thing ?

Comment: Yes. The error is on % mark. when you use backslash PHP should recognize it inside the string as just `%`.

Comment: @dumidu. why are you printing an string and then put it in a variable? There something wrong in your code. `sprintf()` function is useful when you want to print something in user's browser, I don't think this will be useful in your SQL query. I'll post an answer and try to change your code like I do.

Comment: @bcesars Really. Even I didn't think about that. You are an amazing. I fixed it. I really need to rate you.

Comment: @dumidu. Good to know it works. Is posted an answer that could help you. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `sprintf()` function will work to include sql statement and the store into a variable.

Try something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( 
radians('".mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat)."') ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) 
* cos( radians( longitude ) - radians('".mysql_real_escape_string($center_lng)."') ) 
+ sin( radians('".mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat)."') ) 
* sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM condo
 HAVING distance < '".mysql_real_escape_string($radius))."'
 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 2500";
```

And then you can execute your query.

But **BECAREFUL** with mysql_* .

As Jay said in comments is true:

- "Consider using [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*."

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE myfield like '%abc%';
```

You must use '
(single quotes)

Comment: FROM condo WHERE developer LIKE '%Lanterra%'

I try. but it also not working.

Comment: @ErasmoOliveira sorry. what you mean by "Manowar rules \m/" ?

Answer (score 2):

Please, take care of this:

- **Inside sprintf strinf format '%' characters must be escaped as '%%'**.
- Only char strings must be single quoted with [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string).
- mysql_* functions are deprecated, you must use prepared statements with mysqli or PDO:

  - [Prepared statements with mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli.prepare).
  - [Prepared statements with PDO](http://php.net/pdo.prepare).

#### Nested query:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM (SELECT *,
    ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians( %F ) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) *
    cos( radians( longitude ) - radians( %F ) ) + sin( radians( %F ) ) *
    sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM condo WHERE
    developer LIKE '%%Lanterra%%') WHERE distance < %F
    ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 2500",
    floatval($center_lat),
    floatval($center_lng),
    floatval($center_lat),
    floatval($radius)
);
```

#### Original query:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians( %F ) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) *
    cos( radians( longitude ) - radians( %F ) ) + sin( radians( %F ) ) *
    sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM condo HAVING distance < %F
    WHERE developer LIKE '%%Lanterra%%' 
    ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 2500",
        floatval($center_lat),
        floatval($center_lng),
        floatval($center_lat),
        floatval($radius)
);
```

Best regards.

Comment: What error? Could you write it? PS: Ahhh, sorry! distance couldn't be used in ORDER BY! wait a minute :) I'll write a nested statement.

Comment: Warning: sprintf(): Too few arguments in C:\wamp\www\gmap\test.php on line 30

Comment: Now both of them will escape sprintf. %Landerra% could be misinterpreted because %L could be a special char, so we need to write it as \%Landerra\%. Try now.

Comment: Yes. % mark is the problem. but '\%Lanterra\%' also shows same error.

Comment: Sorry!! %% as single %! Hahaha. Try again, write %% instead \% or single %.

Comment: This type of problems could be easily avoided using prepared statements from mysqli_* functions (or object mysqli) or using PDO. Take a look: http://php.net/mysqli.prepare and http://php.net/pdo.prepare

Comment: You can still using sprintf, but remember not to quote numbers (only strings) and to escape % characters with double % (%%) inside format string.

Comment: like '%%myString%%' worked for me using SQLAlchemy/Python/PyCharm

Answer (score 0):

You can try instead double quotes "
I've never used the LIKE keyword without them.

```
SELECT * FROM `db`.`table` WHERE `time` LIKE "%20150105%";
```

Comment: It is not this much simple.